# Overfull with two columns, one small box and one big box, how can I deal with the overfull without breaking the boxes?

Tags: boxes, two-column

I have a `twocolumn` document with some sections where I use some box type of content (`tcolorbox` for instance)

On one of the page, I have two boxes, one small and one big.
The big one is too big to fit in the first column, creating a `Warning` of type `overfull`, also breaking the first column layout in the process with some large vertical spaces.

[image: Page]

I looked for answers by looking up `overfull` and got basically the gist that I should rework the boxes/the content so that the warning disappear.

But what if I can't break the boxes (the boxes of my real document would look ugly if I did) ? How do I avoid the breakout of the layout of my page ?

I have the following ME :

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\XeTeXdefaultencoding utf-8
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{B section}
\vbox{
\blindtext
}
\vbox{
\blindtext[2]
}
\end{document}
```

I use KOMA-script classes for my real document but the problem still exists with its two column so I am guessing it is more fundamental.

Comment: `\begin{figure*}... \end{figure*}`?

Comment: Like this ?   
   `\begin{figure*}
    \vbox{
    \blindtext
    }
    \end{figure*}
    \begin{figure*}
    \vbox{
    \blindtext[2]
    }
\end{figure*}`
I tried putting them both in one figure as well, same result

The result is that they are rendered in the following page and in a one-column layout.

Comment: You need to make your box breakable. This is with `tcolorbox` possible.

Comment: Either you use breakable boxes or you have them float. `figure` for a one column float. `figure*` for a two column float, if you want them together. (I read the question as wanting the boxes side-by-side, but maybe that is not what is wanted. Or you rework the content or structure of the document. Put it this way: what do you *want* LaTeX to do? What do you *want* the result to be? That is not at all clear to me right now.

Comment: I want the first column with section, subsection, small box

and the second column with the big box

but no wasted vertical space between section and subsection, and subsection and small box


Also as I said before `figure*` did not work for a two column float, I got a one column float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image: boxes]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{B section}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \blindtext
\end{minipage}
\vfill
\mbox{}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\blindtext[2]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

**Disclaimer:** Note that SE has decided not to include any images again. Until it decides otherwise, I have no way of checking that screenshots display correctly within my posts. I have zero idea why SE does this. Perhaps it is a feature.